# Download Spring 4 source with Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

I have the following dependencies in my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.7.RELEASE")
}
```

How do I get the source code for these libraries?

Comment: Are you asking for download links?

Comment: I'm asking for how do I put it in my build.gradle so it brings it down along with he libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Eclipse then the Eclipse plugin does this for you.

Install the eclipse plugin by adding apply plugin: "eclipse" to your build.gradle file. Then run gradle eclipse to generate the Eclipse .project, .classpath and .settings files. The plugin will download all available sources automatically and add references them in the .classpath file (see the sourcepath attribute of theclasspathentry element).

Hope this is what you needed. Kindly let me know if another solution is needed